# Print a chessboard without using loops, is it possible?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming

Like this: (Ideally in Java, Scala, C# but any well established computer language will do as well) so not pseudo code:

```
B W B W B W B W
W B W B W B W B
B W B W B W B W
W B W B W B W B
B W B W B W B W
W B W B W B W B
B W B W B W B W
W B W B W B W B
```

Comment: `printf("B W B W..\nW B...");`. Code can be generated during make. Using loops...

Answer (score 0):

Techincally, I assume, it is quite easy (pseudo code):

```
function PrintFields(int index) {
  int x=index % 8;
  int y=index / 8;
  int bw=index % 2;
  print_at(x,y,(bw==0)?'B':'W');
  if (index<63) PrintFields(index+1);
}
```

The question is, **WHY ON EARTH** would someone do that?

**EDIT**

I forgot the end condition, which is now in place

Comment: Not sure this will work. Please see the expected output carefully. In answer to your question it's an interesting problem so **WHY ON EARTH NOT**.

Comment: Please see the expected output carefully.

Comment: I did look at the expected output - please elaborate!